# Screen brightness setting for reading on Ubuntu 12.04

Tags: ubuntu, display, brightness, display-settings, backlight

I read a lot on my computer especially at night. Can I somehow set the screen brightness level on my laptop even lower than the Brightness menu does?

Answer (score 0):

You can increase gamma once you achieved maximum brightness level. Or use high contrast screen colors for better readiblity.

Answer (score 0):

You can try with xrandr, use it like this:

```
xrandr --output LVDS1 --brightness 0.8
```

You can set gamma through xrandr too:

```
xrandr --output LVDS1 --gamma 0.9:0.9:0.9 --brightness 0.8
```

To get the output name (*in this example LVDS1*) use:

```
xrandr
```